Why is `gem clean` reporting multiple ambiguous references to the default psych gem?
Problem
For the past several version of macOS (including Sequoia) and with Ruby 3.4.x (and specifically with Ruby 3.4.4 and 3.4.5) anytime I attempt to clean up the psych gem I get the following error:
$ gem cleanup --debug --backtrace psych
NOTE:  Debugging mode prints all exceptions even when rescued
Cleaning up installed gems...
WARN: Unresolved or ambiguous specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      psych (>= 4.0.0)
      Available/installed versions of this gem:
      - 5.1.2
      - 5.1.2
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs. Try 'gem cleanup <gem>'
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Clean up complete

Psych 5.1.2 is a default gem, so I've also tried gem pristine psych but get the same results. It's therefore not obvious which of the other installed or default gems is considering this an "unresolved or ambiguous spec" in the dependency chain.
This is not causing a functional problem with C Ruby 3.3.5 as far as I can tell. It just always results in gem clean exiting with warnings.
Checking Dependencies and Debugging
In an effort to figure out where this might be coming from, I also ran:
$ gem dependency psych
Gem psych-5.1.2
  stringio (>= 0)

Gem psych-5.1.2
  stringio (>= 0)

Not so useful. But when I check the reverse dependencies on psych, I find:
$ gem dependency -R psych
Gem psych-5.1.2
  stringio (>= 0)
  Used by
    rdoc-6.7.0 (psych (>= 4.0.0))
    rdoc-6.6.3.1 (psych (>= 4.0.0))

Gem psych-5.1.2
  stringio (>= 0)
  Used by
    rdoc-6.7.0 (psych (>= 4.0.0))
    rdoc-6.6.3.1 (psych (>= 4.0.0))

That appears to be the source of the problem, since gem list rdoc returns:

rdoc (6.7.0, default: 6.6.3.1)

However, because rdoc v6.6.3.1 is a default gem, I can't seem to uninstall it. Assuming this is actually the problem, I tried:
$ gem uninstall -v 6.6.3.1 --force rdoc
Gem rdoc-6.6.3.1 cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem

$ gem pristine -v 6.6.3.1  rdoc
Restoring gems to pristine condition...
Skipped rdoc-6.6.3.1, it is a default gem

Attempts to Find Others' Examples
If this is indeed the problem, I have no idea how to debug it further or resolve the "ambiguous specs" error. My Google-fu returned no useful results, and searing on Stack Overflow for [ruby] Gem::Specification.reset psych doesn't return anything that fits my particular use case.

you have one psych that is the default gem and another that is the regular gem. happens when you gem install psych. you can uninstall it gem uninstall psych and let the default gem do the work.

@Alex This is probably true, so I upvoted your comment, but I was unable to actually test it. After upgrading the OS, the compiler, and updating all gems this week, the problem simply went away on its own even though all gem versions listed in the original question remain the same. I'm therefore assuming it's something to do with the compiler, or possibly just with the latest version of rubygems. In any case, I can't reproduce the problem any longer, so I can't fully validate your answer, but it seems truthy and may help someone else. Thank you!
